# RSS feed without items

Tags: rss

I have webpage where I have a search page. I provide a "dynamic" RSS feed for search so that a user can subscribe to search results for any search term he likes.

So I was wondering what is the standard (or best practise) way to do if that search term returns 0 results which means I have no "items" to put in the feed. Do I just return an empty feed (only including the meta data and no `item` elements). Or should I put some special `item` element in the feed with some "no results" text?

edit: YouTube returns a feed without any `item` elements. If no-one can answer me I'll take it that this is the right way of doing it since I can't find any info elsewhere :)

Comment: Good question, I have the same unsolved problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the [least surprising thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and return an empty feed - the structure remains the same as with any other RSS feed, but there are no `item` elements.

Bogus feed results that are actually not results are more trouble than they're worth, stemming from the fact that you would be presenting metadata ("n results") as a row of data ("content of result #x"): "you have 1 new item: 'ha ha just kidding, no new items for you'" is confusing both for users *and* user agents.

As for "but users will think it's broken if they don't get any results": if they don't get any meaningful results, they'll think it's broken *either way*, but getting a "there is 1 message: there is no message" will probably confuse them more.

Moreover, it will confuse the *user agents* (RSS reader programs): most of them keep the old items locally and keep them (unless the *user* requests to delete the items), so you'd see a list of "item 1,item 2,there are currently no items, item 3, item 4, item 5, item 6, there are currently no items, item 7".

Edit: before you take the user to the RSS feed, you could show some sort of preview - e.g. "here's the link to your feed, which currently contains *n* results". (Of *course* some users won't read it and complain anyway, but there's only so much we can do about that)

Comment: I am wondering if this solution makes a good user experience. They could think the feed is broken or they did something wrong..?!

Comment: @Simon: How is it different from an existing feed which has no *new* items? Would you expect that a feed without new items will pop up an item saying "this feed intentionally left blank"? Are we responsible for all the possible RSS user agents that can't/won't distinguish between "no new items" and "broken feed"? Also, the users will also think the feed is broken if they get "no new items" item, as this is something which I have yet to see anywhere else ("users are more familiar with *other* sites than with *your* site").

Comment: Yes, of course. You are right in every point you write. But I know users that do not know how the internet works. I am worrying about them, not the user agents. If they click a RSS icon in firefox that leads to a grey empty page, they might not hit the subscribe-button on it. And *other* sites do not return empty feeds that often.

Maybe its just the fault of the "agents" like firefox that do not display a "no items at the moment" sign.

Comment: @Simon: What about a preview (see my edit)? Also, this specific feature is a dynamically generated feed from a search - such as you can see here: http://www.maandag.nl/Vacatures/ (click the "ontvang vacatures via RSS" in the left menu). One would expect that users of such advanced feature would be slightly more savvy than "teh intertubez, it iz broken" variety (and anyway, there is only so much that we can fix. Clueless users are not on that list.)

Comment: @Simon: You're welcome. Now I realize we have a great example of such preview right before our eyes: see the SO tag searches - each has a RSS feed associated, so *the results on the page itself* is actually the preview for the RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

Tell them there's no search results. It's only polite!

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? How should the message be formatted, in what element should it appear in, etc. And I'm not looking for a polite solution but a correct one :)

Comment: I think number of search results in the the `<channel>`'s `<description>` would be good, and leave no `<item>` s. Like: `<channel><title>Title</title><description>Search Terms - X results found.</description></channel>`